# Confused with a Laravel syntax error: unexpected '.' (seems fine to me)

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to Laravel.

I keep getting this syntax error:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
syntax error, unexpected '.'
```

The line in question is this:

```
  $post = .\DB::table('posts')->where('slug', $slug)->first();
```

Here's the entire code that is not working:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class PostsController extends Controller

{
  public function show($slug)
  {
    $post = .\DB::table('posts')->where('slug', $slug)->first();

    dd($post);

     // This was to simulate a database
     // $posts = [
     //   'my-first-post' => 'Hello This is my first blog post',
     //   'my-second-post' => 'Hello This is my second blog post',
     // ];

     // if it doesn't exist then throw this error:
     if (! array_key_exists($post, $posts)){
       abort(404, 'Sorry, that post was not found.');
     }

     // return this view:
      return view('post', [
        'post' => $posts[$post]
      ]);
  }

}
```

What is it that I am missing here!?

Thanks

Comment: what do you think using the `.` is doing for the `$post` assignment? and why do you think that is fine?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `.\`.
Please change your code `$post = .\DB::table('posts')->where('slug', $slug)->first();` with `$post = DB::table('posts')->where('slug', $slug)->first();` and don't forget to import DB `use DB`

Comment: don't need to alias `DB` if they call it as the FQCN, `\DB` ... it is just the `.` that is the problem

Comment: It is okay to not alias, but is much easier to import the class/facade or alias and then just simply call it inside a function. People makes small mistakes like my friend Henry did, becasue they don't know how to call a class directly inside a function...

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `./` after variable `$post`  so change this line to

```
  $post = DB::table('posts')->where('slug', $slug)->first();
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

[image: Laravel Tutorial]

Like me, you have clearly been working through the laracast tutorial.
For some reason the IDE being used makes the '\' look like a '.\'

Here is how it looks in VS code
[image: VS code]

Just remove the full stop and you'll be fine!

Comment: The answer kind of needs an image. The problem this user has had is due to the way the code is graphically displayed on a tutorial. A typed extract would not demonstrate the same artefact.
If you would like the code in text let me know, I'd be happy to share that for you.

Comment: Oh! I didn't know that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

edit your Code to:

```
$post = DB::table('posts')->where('slug', $slug)->first();
```

and import DB at the top:

```
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```